# I can't receive SMS when I have low storage

Tags: sms, internal-storage

From the time the "low storage" warning appears no synchronization is done at all, including receiving SMS.

Can I do anything about it? Can I "force" my Motorola Milestone Froyo to receive SMS somehow?

This is really annoying. Especially because the user doesn't informed in detail. I missed a lot of SMS... I hope that gets fixed in Froyo.

Comment: Did not get fixed in froyo. ;(

Comment: Same question asked 1 year later http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12275/how-to-stop-rejecting-messages-at-low-memory

Comment: Google says, they fixed it in Android 2.3. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4991#c257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4991

This is bug. You must always make sure you have free space in Android, otherwise the bug might happened.

Comment: Thank you! While looking over the 400+ user comments at your link (and the linked issues there) I see I am not alone ;)

Answer (score 2):

SMS, etc. are stored on internal storage.  If it's getting full, then you'll have to uninstall some apps to free up space to receive more messages.  Not much else you can do about this.

My suggestion, however, is that you use an app like [SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) to backup your old SMS messages to a label in gmail.  Then you can delete old threads which will free up space AND you'll still have a copy of all of your messages.

Comment: Well, first of all I am not willing to seek the fault at the user. I know that this could have been developed way better. Motorola bound the SMS receiving process to the sync manager which is blocked when memory is low. That's the(ir) fault. SMS don't take much space and won't harm the system! Backing up SMS doesn't help, because the freed space is too tiny for the sync manager to recognize. That reminds me of times where only 10 SMS could be saved on a SIM.

Comment: I agree that more complete notification would be nice, but ultimately this seems 100% reasonable behavior to me. Your phone has some idea of how much space it needs to handle phone calls and otherwise function properly. If your phone doesn't think it has sufficient space to keep downloading data and still function properly, it should stop downloading new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing older messages, most default messaging apps have an option somewhere in their settings (you'll have to look around depending on your device - I don't have a Milestone) and somewhere the should be a tickbox "Delete old messages" - tick that and set the limits and the phone will delete older messages, freeing up space (on the internal memory, as Bryan said) meaning you can receive more messages.
If you **do** need all your old messages, see Bryan's way

Comment: See my comment to Bryans answer. Deleting old SMS frees only very little space. The sync manager won't recognize it. It doesn't follow the basic logic of old fashioned phones, where you have a fixed and reserved storage for SMS. Thats why your suggested option doesn't have much impact ;(

Answer (score 0):

Plz also see that date/time settings. Correct date and time of the instrument is very important for all correspondence related to messages