# Why am I getting a "Low on Space" warning and having other weird problems?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, internal-storage

Yesterday I got a warning that the "phone storage space is low." Because of that I can't receive SMS messages. I tried to uninstall applications - the system shows me that the application is being uninstalled but after restart I see the application again (i.e. I tried to remove Adobe AIR - 16 MB). Also when I try to delete threads of messages, it doesn't delete theme. The weirdest thing is that after I "free" space and I check the internal storage in the system phone storage setting, I see that the available space in the internal phone storage is lower than before...

Moreover I can't install any application that can help me: cache cleaner or something else.

Does someone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: One of these three similar questions should help:  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-can-i-free-up-more-space-on-my-android-2-2-froyo-phone http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/cant-receive-sms-on-my-motorola-milestone-when-internal-storage-is-almost-full

Comment: See here how Android calculates your personal space limit: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4991#c145

Answer (score 1):

first thing you should check is if you can move large applications to SD. 
Go to

> Settings, Applications, Manage applications, All

There you can select applications and check if they can be moved to your SD card.
After you've moved some applications to your SD card you will be able to install other applications and get back the functionality you've been missing.

A similar question to have a look at is [question 5519](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with my Droid Incredible. What I've found is that unmounting and then remounting the SD card (Settings->SD & phone storage->Unmount SD card) usually resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't install those cache cleaner apps, sometimes clearing the Browser's cache would help. However, you will keep getting this problem.