# Low disk space notification, but heaps of space free

Tags: notifications, internal-storage

A few days ago I put two large files (about 300MB all up) on the phone storage. I got a low space notification.

I connected the phone via USB to a Windows XP machine and deleted the files, but I still had the notification.

I have emptied trash. I have also connected via linux and done a find -printf '%b %p' to find the biggest files and the two that I originally put on are definitely gone.

I deleted even more cached files and now windows explorer reports 720MB (about 60%) free.

I am still getting the low space notification even after a reboot of the phone. How can I get rid of the notification?

HTC Desire running Android 2.2 with Sense. Thanks for any help rendered!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your phone's internal storage, via Menu > Settings > SD & phone storage, and then look under Internal Phone Storage. If that's looking low, then you can try uninstalling some apps, or, since you're on 2.2, moving those that support it to your SD card (as that does seem to have plenty of space).

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you! I didn't know the distinction between phone and sd ram.

Comment: I still had very limited space after moving all my apps (those that were possible to move) to the SD, any other solutions?

Comment: @Asaf - not really, other than uninstalling some apps you don't use or can live without.  You can clear data and caches for an app, but that's not really a solution as the app will likely just recreate everything whilst in use.

Comment: Isn't it a bit odd? I have about 10 apps, and I'm seeing iPhone users with 50 apps and no problems.. seems that a market share have been bluntly ignored here

Comment: @Asaf - what phone do you have? Some phones do sadly have quite inadequate internal storage. I have a Desire HD, which seems to have more than enough space for me.

Comment: Yeah I just read the specs, sadly I have Desire, which has about 1gb less.. currently have 14mb free and maybe 20 apps I installed myself.. ridiculous

Comment: @Asaf - This question might help a bit? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless

Answer (score 0):

On HTC Phones, I found one big space stealer is the "Facebook for HTC Sense" app. It can easily take up 20+ mb of data. It is worth checking it out and clearing data (not cache)