# Is some of my internal memory missing?

Tags: internal-storage, htc-wildfire

I have an HTC Wildfire (the original, not the S version). It is supposed to have 512MB of memory. When I check my free space in the app manager I noticed I have around 185MB. Why is this?

I am using CyanogenMod which is around 80MB, if this wasn't accounted for there is still a lot of space missing. Why is my phone reporting so little?

Comment: The download may be 80 MB, but it's compressed. The real size is much larger. Your apps and data also take up space.

Comment: I just decompressed the zip of my rom. it is 110mb. supposing that the app manager is reporting only apps (115 used mb) I am still missing more than 50%.

Comment: possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6452/low-disk-space-notification-but-heaps-of-space-free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok. here is the thing. The space is there, the problem is that it is not accesible for applications.

Android systems have several partitions as explained  [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/). Doing an df on my device I get:

```
Filesystem              Size      Used      Available Use%    Mounted on
tmpfs                   156.5M     32.0K   156.4M     0%    /dev
tmpfs                   156.5M         0   156.5M     0%    /mnt/asec
tmpfs                   156.5M         0   156.5M     0%    /mnt/obb
/dev/block/mtdblock3    250.0M    119.0M   131.0M     48%   /system
/dev/block/mtdblock5    175.1M    157.2M   18.0M      90%   /data
/dev/block/mtdblock4    40.0M      1.3M    38.7M      3%    /cache
/dev/block/vold/179:1   3.7G      2.8G     952.5M     75%   /mnt/sdcard
```

the space I see in the app manager is the same allocated for /data, the rest of the space is used for the cache and the android system (in the /system and /cache partitions).

A solution would be to find out how to resize the partitions in the internal memory of the phone (there is a procedure [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1233340)). Another solution (which seems easier) is to put they regularly used apps in the /system partition along with the default applications so that all memory is used (root is needed)