# Installation error on android - out of storage

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage, installation, lg-optimus-2x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “insufficient storage” wrongly reported when installing an .apk via adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/why-is-insufficient-storage-wrongly-reported-when-installing-an-apk-via-adb)

I have a very weird problem. I am trying to install an apk from on my phone. I have tried directly of the sdcard, and with my computer with adb. None of them seem to work. It says that i have to free space and try again. And adb says error, insufficient storage. But when i install an apk from the market which is alot bigger. It goes fine. I have checked my storage in settings. And i have more that enough free storage on my external and internal sdcard. The apk i'm trying to install takes about 4-5 MB, and i have atleast 1GB free on my internal and external card. My phone is an LG Optimus 2X P990

Comment: Could you please check whether one of the Q&As (to the right in the "Linked" section) may apply and solve your problem? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/why-is-insufficient-storage-wrongly-reported-when-installing-an-apk-via-adb / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14731/htc-incredible-says-sms-storage-is-full-but-it-isnt