# Installing GalnetMIUI Rom on HTC Desire

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

I Have an HTC DESIRE which I upgraded to Gingerbread recently. My friend told me about Galnet MIUI for Desire, and now I want to root my device. Is this possible? These are my phone's specs:

```
HTC DESIRE
Android Version  2.3.3
Base band version - 32.56.00.32U_5.17.05.23
Kernel Version 2.6.35.10-g3f43272
Build No 3.14.405.1 CL 96875
```

Comment: The "low storage space" issue has been covered in the past (particularly regarding the Desire). You can take a look at [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help) for some good information.

Comment: Also related: [How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

- Rooting allows you to install a custom recovery (Clockwork Mod or AmonRa) to install ROMs
- S-OFF allows you to change the HBOOT to rearrange your internal partitions

I rooted with [Unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/recovery/) before I used [Alpharev's S-OFF](http://alpharev.nl/) some months later

Nowadays it's easier apparently. You can get S-OFF with [Unrevoked Forever](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/forever) too but I'm not sure your phone is supported. And Unrevoked/Alpharev teamed up for [revolutionary](http://revolutionary.io/)

Finally, there are many ROMS out there, some are better then others. I use [Oxygen](http://forum.oxygen.im/) personally with the Oxygen HBOOT for 330MB internal data space. I'd use Devnull (same developers) but it doesn't have long press to kill

Answer (score 1):

For rooting HTC Desire 2.3.3 official update you have to use [revolutionary.io](http://revolutionary.io/) beta app. Its very simple process. You've to download the program on your computer (Windows/Linux), get the beta key from the website and follow the steps the program asks you to do. I've written a detailed blog [here](http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/perm-root-htc-desire-gingerbread-233.html) if you want.