# How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

I have an [HTC Desire](http://www.htc.com/europe/help/htc-desire/) (Bravo, A8181, GSM) sold in Sweden. I updated it to Android 2.3 using the official release, which is as of 2011-12-29 available at [HTCdev](http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads) with instructions from [here](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-update-htc-desire-to-android-2-3-gingerbread-50004625/).

Now I want to root it. I did some googling and it seems like it isn't possible to root a Desire that has been updated to the official Android 2.3. I tried following [this guide](http://www.htcdesireforum.com/htc-desire-how-to/%28guide%29-rootin-flashing-rom/), but it failed at step 6 in *How to: Root*. When I attempted to run [unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/), the progress text `running root...` was followed by the error message `Error: failed to get root. Is your firmware too new?`.

I also tried searching for a way to downgrade it to Android 2.2, with no luck.

How can I root this phone?

Comment: I also have a blog post on how to root HTC Desire 2.3.3. http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/perm-root-htc-desire-gingerbread-233.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my searching I stumbled across [Revolutionary](http://revolutionary.io/). It looked good enough, so I downloaded it and ran it. It prompted me to plug my phone in, and then it pretty much did the rest on its own. The result was that a custom recovery system was set up, from which it is easy to install ROMs and the like to the phone.

The [Revolutionary docs](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/revolutionary) mentions a zip file you need to install in order to root the phone. In order to install the zip file, I first downloaded it to my phone's SD card. Revolutionary only sets up the mentioned recovery system, so the official HTC Android 2.3 was still intact and running on the phone. I used that to mount the SD card on my computer and copy the zip file, but I could just as well have done it using Revolutionary.

After placing the zip file on my SD card, I shut down the phone, then held the *volume down* button and pressed the power button. This results in starting the phone's bootloader, from where one can start the recovery system (Revolutionary in my case). This greeted me with a neat menu containing the entry *install zip from sdcard*. I selected this and navigated to the zip file I downloaded. When the installation was complete, I rebooted the phone into Android, and my app drawer now contained the Superuser app. Root complete!