# What's the best method for rooting HTC Desire?

Tags: rooting, 2.2-froyo, htc-desire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/how-to-root-a-htc-desire-running-official-android-2-3)

What's the best method for rooting HTC Desire?

Do I need both S-OFF and root? How are these two things related?

I essentially want to root because I am often short on space so I want to be able to store apps and associated data on the SD memory card instead of the internal phone memory. For this I will need root, right?

Comment: AFAIK, S-OFF is security off, which is a pre-requisite for flashing custom roms..read, installing a custom recovery/kernel/ROM...

Comment: S-Off is a hardware based write protect scheme for the storage area, i.e. the flash region where the system data resides gets set read-only during boot. There's a hacked bootloader available at http://alpharev.nl that doesn't write-protect that region when booting and leaves it writable the normal way. S-Off is thus a prerequisite for modding/rooting.

Comment: I just added the `rooting` tag to your question. Please hover your mouse over it for more information, and follow the hints there. We have a central index to find the rooting questions for special devices, and yours is already listed there ([How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/16575)) The answers there should provide you some help ;) Good luck!

Comment: I didn't find the central index you talk about. I did go to the root tag. Where do I find that? Are you talking about the root tag page?... or some kind of Wiki or FAQ for rooting? This phone came with Android 2.2 or maybe 2.1 stock and was probably upgraded OTA to 2.2 (I don't really remember).

Comment: What's the method where you reboot the phone and enter HBoot and then you connect it to USB and use ADB to send some commands and stuff?... where you need to install some driver and HTC Sync? Is that Unrevoked or is that just the way every rooting process starts?...

Answer (score 0):

One of the best methods to root the HTC Desire is to use Unrevoked. It will install root and a custom recovery. You can check the guide in [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=788044)

S-ON (default phone state) will read-lock your `/system` and `/recovery` partitions, so despite being root, you won't be able to modify them. With S-OFF you remove that lock and can make use of root in all the phone. To achieve S-OFF you can use [Revolutionary](http://revolutionary.io/).

I suppose what you want is to use any [App2SD script](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1716124). For that you will need to be root and depending on the script you want to use, you might also need S-OFF to be able to write in `init.d`

Comment: So the system will be stored on the internal phone memory and apps and app data will be stored on SD?

Comment: I was under the impression that Revolutionary can do both, both root and do S-OFF. But if I understand you correctly I need Revolutionary to do S-OFF and Unrevoked for root? I will need both?