# How do I root Android 2.3.3 on HTC Desire?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, htc-desire, unrevoked

I just flashed my HTC Desire with the Android 2.3.3 upgrade from HTC developer website. But now when I try to root it using the Unrevoked (recovery reflash tool) version 3.32 which is what I used the last time, it fails to root it.

Does Unrevoked support rooting 2.3.3?

If not, what other tool or method can I use?

Like I said, I used Unrevoked last time to root 2.29.405.2 and I used AlphaRev to set S-OFF. Is there a way I can flash it with 2.29, root it, set S-OFF, and then only upgrade Android to 2.3.3 without affecting other parts of the system?

I have visited the wiki pages of the Unrevoked project, but there are no specifics about what Android versions are supported.

**Screenshots**

Here are some screenshots of Unrevoked.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

**Update2:**

I used [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/?page_id=2) version 2.3.3.0 and it seemed like it managed to root it. Here's a log.

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""

$ export PS1=""

getprop ro.build.version.release > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=32532

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

2.3.3

END:32532export PS1=""

getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=28422

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

HTC

END:28422export PS1=""

getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=96072

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

HTC Desire

END:96072export PS1=""

getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=51591

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

96875.1

END:51591export PS1=""

ls -l /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=91434

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/system/xbin/su: No such file or directory

END:91434export PS1=""

ls -l /system/bin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=42250

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/system/bin/su: No such file or directory

END:42250export PS1=""

chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=51294

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:51294export PS1=""

/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=26328

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

whoami: unknown uid 2000

END:26328export PS1=""

rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=60490

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

rm failed for /data/local/tmp/boomsh, No such file or directory

END:60490export PS1=""

rm /data/local/tmp/sh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=51670

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

rm failed for /data/local/tmp/sh, No such file or directory

END:51670export PS1=""

chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=73418

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:73418export PS1=""

cd /data/local/tmp/ > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=32307

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:32307export PS1=""

export TEMPRANDOM=46286;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;./zergRush

[**] Zerg rush - Android 2.2/2.3 local root

[**] (C) 2011 Revolutionary. All rights reserved.

[**] Parts of code from Gingerbreak, (C) 2010-2011 The Android Exploid Crew.

[+] Found a GingerBread ! 0x00000118

[*] Scooting ...

[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...

[+] Zerglings found a way to enter ! 0x10

[+] Overseer found a path ! 0x000151e0

[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...

[+] Zerglings caused crash (good news): 0x401219c4 0x0054

[*] Researching Metabolic Boost ...

[+] Speedlings on the go ! 0xafd1950b 0xafd395f7

[*] Popping 24 more zerglings

[*] Sending 173 zerglings ...

[+] Rush did it ! It's a GG, man !

[+] Killing ADB and restarting as root... enjoy!

# export PS1=""

/data/local/tmp/busybox mount -o rw,remount /system > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=20944

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:20944export PS1=""

mkdir /system/xbin > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=80223

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

mkdir failed for /system/xbin, File exists

END:80223export PS1=""

export TEMPRANDOM=98688;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;/data/local/tmp/busybox cat /data/local/tmp/1108121.tmp > /system/xbin/su

cannot create /system/xbin/su: not enough memory

END:98688export PS1=""

export PS1=""

/data/local/tmp/busybox rm /data/local/tmp/1108121.tmp > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=29466

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:29466export PS1=""

chown 0:0 /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=58396

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Unable to chmod /system/xbin/su: No such file or directory

END:58396export PS1=""

chmod 6755 /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=42924

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Unable to chmod /system/xbin/su: No such file or directory

END:42924export PS1=""

export TEMPRANDOM=42250;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;/data/local/tmp/busybox cat /data/local/tmp/5025101.tmp > /system/app/Superuser.apk

cannot create /system/app/Superuser.apk: not enough memory

END:42250export PS1=""

export PS1=""

/data/local/tmp/busybox rm /data/local/tmp/5025101.tmp > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=22516

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:22516export PS1=""

busybox true > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

busybox: not found

export TEMPRANDOM=19154

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:19154export PS1=""

/data/local/tmp/busybox mount -o ro,remount /system > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1
```

Note this part specifically:

```
[+] Found a GingerBread ! 0x00000118
[*] Scooting ...
[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...
[+] Zerglings found a way to enter ! 0x10
[+] Overseer found a path ! 0x000151e0
[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...
[+] Zerglings caused crash (good news): 0x401219c4 0x0054
[*] Researching Metabolic Boost ...
[+] Speedlings on the go ! 0xafd1950b 0xafd395f7
[*] Popping 24 more zerglings
[*] Sending 173 zerglings ...
[+] Rush did it ! It's a GG, man !
[+] Killing ADB and restarting as root... enjoy!
```

It says "restarting as root". But the thing is when I run the Root Checker Basic app it says "sorry! this device does not have proper root access." What gives?

So I'm back on square one again.

**Update 3:**

I tried the GingerBreak tool, as mentioned [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-android-2-3-gingerbread-using-gingerbreak/). I installed the APK manually from my computer with ADB. I then launched the app and let it do its thing. After over 10 minutes without any results I aborted it. It doesn't say in the article if the phone needs to be connected to the computer when you do this. They mention that USB debugging needs to be enabled. I don't understand why if the phone doesn't need to be connected. But I tried both connected and disconnected, didn't work either way I tried.

**Update 4:**

### Use the Revolutionary method!

I would have posted a step by step instruction with screenshots but as you can see the question has been marked as a duplicate and I can no longer post an answer to it. So I can just tell you to go to the "duplicate" question and look for instructions there (the link on top of this page).

Comment: Sammy, you might always want to take a look into our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17587/16575) before asking "how to root..." (btw, our tag-wikis, here [rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), are pretty good resources to find such ;) -- [How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17587/16575) should answer your question and tell you the correct tool to use :)

Comment: So Revolutionary is the answer? Isn't that based on Unrevoked?... and it has been a developer preview for at least a year without any official release for the "mass destruction" of rooted devices. I'm desperate, so I'll give that a go anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I cannot give you more details on this -- I just picked the question for you, as it perfectly matched :)

Comment: I also have a blog post on how to root HTC Desire 2.3.3. http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/perm-root-htc-desire-gingerbread-233.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I got root and S-OFF now using Revolutionary. About that Beta key... do I need to safe keep it? Or will I be able to generate a new one next time? I'm not sure why that is needed. Just because the tool is in Beta development stage?...

Answer (score 1):

Since HTC provides a tool to unlock the bootloader on there phones why not use the official tool... http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that last night. Though I'm not sure how this will help me. So what if I do unlock the bootloader? Does it give me root access?

Comment: If you unlock the bootloader you can easily root without any hacks, you can flash any mod without hacks.