# My HTC Desire has suddenly become full and is displaying the "Disk Space Low!" Message

Tags: htc-desire, internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTC Desire low on internal storage, I'm clueless — Any help?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help)

I have always had a problem with my Desire's phone storage capacity so recently I did a factory re-set and started again.  Everything was fine for a few weeks, I had loads of space and could download and install to my hearts content.  Then all of a sudden I have the dreaded "Disk Space Low!" message again.  Thsi is despite having only 39.116meg of apps installed on the phone. All possiable apps are on the sd card and there is nothing in the cache.  Also all contacts, dates etc are stored on google.

Can someone please explain what is taking up all this space i.e all 139 MB?  I cant even download the latest software update!

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing your disk usage with [DiskUsage](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage), it helps visualize the problem.