# Not enough storage on android device

Tags: htc-desire, storage, htc

When I download application from Market I obtain out of memory error.

In fact I have about 2Gb free storage on SD Card and it seems there is out of space of internal phone storage.

How to clear internal storage? E.g. remove some cache files or somewhat else?

How to obtain access to phone storage?
(When I connect my android device to PC without SD card I even have no choice to connect as a disc)

I moved all application which can be moved to Android device with [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.app2sd).

It is really annoying - I have memory of SD Card but in fact I can not use it.

My device is HTC Desire, Android 2.3.3

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at [HTC Desire low on internal storage, I'm clueless — Any help?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help)

Comment: I have not found answer there

Comment: So you didn't find any of the *ten* answers there to be of any help? Can you explain a bit what differentiates your case from all of those or what it is that you're looking for? As currently worded this certainly seems like it would be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: There are no any accepted answer there. Have you noticed this? Moreover some answers are just describing problem on similar environment. And for some answers I am too stupid to understand them. Or do you beleive that I want to wait for answer here instead of just reading answer which already exist? That answers do not save time for me - as a result I have no sence in this site on such circumstances

Comment: Memory or storage? There is a difference.

Comment: @Al Everett I meant phone storage, not internal memory. I updated question, seems more clear now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably your internal memory is too low.

**You can't access it without rooting your device. And it won't be visible in your PC/desktop anyways with a USB connection. (it can't be mounted)**

From what I understand your HTC Desire device has 512 MB of internal ROM which is used for both your stock firmware and user installed apps.

The 512 MB storage may be divided into several partitions. System partition holds your ROM (firmware) and may include apps which came per-installed when you purchased the device.

The data partition is where your apps are stored. To check, how much actual space you have for data partition-

> Go to Settings -> Applications menu.

You should get a list of installed apps with available storage at bottom like this,

[image: Applications Menu on Android 2.3]

This will be the actual memory available to you. To increase this, you could try

1. Moving apps to SD Card (which I believe you have already tried).
2. Root your device and delete unwanted system apps (bloatware)
3. Install a custom ROM, with app2sd/data2sd scripts, which enables you to use a ext3/ext4 partition on your SD card to use for installing apps. ( A  1GB partition would do fine.)

Although there is a alternative too, which can help you **move some of the apps** which are by default not enabled for moving to SD Card.

> *Requirements*
>
> 1. An Android Device (Obviously.. ) (Root not required)
> 2. USB Cable
> 3. A PC (Any OS will do Windows, Mac or Linux)
> 4. Android SDK or replacement for ADB (Install android sdk from official site. Use drivers for your device)

*Steps*

> 1. Run command prompt or terminal use command '**adb devices**' (will show
>      list of connected devices) (you should have android sdk's
>      path/platform-tools in your classpath)
> 2. use command '**adb shell**' (will open a $ prompt)
> 3. use command '**pm setInstallLocation 2**' ( will set default install
>      location to sd card )
>
>    (0 for auto, 1 for internal, 2 for sd card )

Now whatever new apps you install will be installed to sd card. they will still take space on internal memory in data partition though for dalvik cache, app-cache, private-cache etc.

Note-> If you want to revert back to original use option 0 in step 4.

I have seen some weird behavior with this, apps which are set to install in SD Card by default (i.e. games like angry bird), are installed in internal. You could just move them to external though. My advice would be to use this command to enable moving to sd card and then revert back.

Comment: My device seems rooted - I asked about this, but I don't know how to check this for sure. Where is "bloatware" located which could be removed paintless? Where is ext3/ext4 on sdcard? I can not find it in ASTRO file manager.

Comment: Check your device is rooted or not here - [Root Checker Basic - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck).  **Bloatware** is not exactly defined for android phones. I meant to say that there are some android apps and widgets on your devices which you may never use or have better alternatives, in that case those app can be said as bloatware for you because you can't delete them easily as they came pre-installed on your device. The ext3/ext4 partition would have to be created by you with a partitioning tool and your ROM would need app2sd/data2sd support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I finally rooted my phone. Used article http://androidpage.ru/htc-desire-poluchaem-prava-root-i-s-off-na-oficialnoj-proshivke-android-2-3-3/ (in Russian though). I have app2sd installed, but I have not found how to move preinstalled software to SD card. Is it something special become available in app2sd after rooting? or something else?

Comment: Finally I successfully done this! Moreover. If preinstalled software is upgraded it should be removed completely first. And after execution of "pm setInstallLocation 2" existing software can be moved to SD-card from phone memory.

Comment: For those out there with a Samsung S3 like me, the `pm set-install-location 2` just doesn't work. At least as far as I could try, and try, and try. Seems like Samsung has changed how that works on its custom ROM, but I couldn’t find more info on that.

Comment: BEWARE. There's a [dangerous caveat here!](http://droid-den.com/android-guides/android-guide-force-apps-to-the-sd-card-without-rooting-a2sd/)

Some apps will start to break and malfunction if they are installed on the external sd card. Such as those that require a background service running all times, like ALL widgets, twitter, instant messages, etc.

Comment: The `pm` command has changed to `set-install-location`, at least on adb 1.0.31.

Answer (score 3):

Clearing internal storage will probably be a temporary relief only, as it will fill-up again in (probably short) time. However, depending on the action the "temporary span" can be quite long -- so if you are afraid to root and to follow the steps recommended in the other answers, here's a list of possibilities:

- uninstall apps you do not need
- if possible, move apps rarely used to external storage (App2SD)
- cleanup cache (and, optionally, data from apps where you could start-over)

While the first 2 items should be clear, some explanation on the 3rd. You can do that manually without any special app (in case you are already unable to install any) -- but it's a bit wearing:

1. Go to your homescreen
2. Hit the "menu" key, select "settings"
3. Select "Apps" (or "Applications" -- the name differs between devices and Android versions)
4. Select "Manage Apps" (or "Manage Applications", see above)
5. Now select each app, one by one, and hit the "Clear Cache" button. If you want to remove the apps data as well, hit the "Clear Data" button, too.

Note that clearing cache is non-destructive, as it only removes temporary files -- while claring data is not, as it will remove all data you stored with the app, including its settings.

If you are still able to install apps, this hairy process can be eased up a lot by some little helpers like e.g. [1-Tap Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free) or [Easy Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bazinga.cacheclean).

Comment: I rooted it and obtained other issues such as hand up the phone and similar. Concenring memory, it just temporary helped as you said. Finally I switched to iPhone and happy with it.

Comment: Oh -- OK, that's a quite different approach to a solution :D Thank you for providing this info, so we know you are no longer "in urgent need" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly worth rooting your phone if you feel capable and are running out of space.

On my Desire, I moved caches to SD and regularly run a cache cleaner.  I also deleted lots of bloatware.

If you want to run lots of apps you have to work at it on a Desire!

Comment: How have you moved caches to SD?

Answer (score -1):

It is due to an error in the OS itself. Even some simple apps could not be installed while some bigger apps could.

Reset the device to factory mode and then you must be able to install the same apps which were denied before.