# "Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app

Tags: internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory

Every time I go to install a new app, I get the message "Insufficient storage", and an unable to install *anything*!

I am using Samsung GT19060 my internal memory is 8GB. I have not downloaded anything but anytime I try to download something it will tell me low memory space.

Comment: Clearing the data of Google Play or the Android Market may free up some space. You could also check with the [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) app to find out how data is structured on the internal memory and then delete any unused data.

Comment: how do I clear the data on the android market?

Comment: Should be something like `Settings | Applications | Play Store | Clear data`. Might help to "Force Stop" the app first.

Comment: This problem is related or even identical to the one described here: [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it/27130#27130), so the list of possible steps to take described there might help you as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: 25 MB free internal storage is minimum requirement (source: [TechniPages](http://www.technipages.com/droid-text-message-memory-full.html), [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-replenish/204368-text-message-memory-full-cant-send.html)). If free space falls below that, the "insufficient storage" error is triggered.

For details, see:

- [Why does my phone keep telling me it has low storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26647/16575)
- [Not enough storage on android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21943/16575)
- [Android “Internal Storage” used but not reported](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/16575)
- [I keep getting storage errors but I have plenty of free space, what is safe to remove from internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32660/16575)
- [HTC Desire low on internal storage, I'm clueless — Any help?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/16575)
- [Message Memory Full, Incoming message rejected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/16575)

And many more -- this is a quite "frequent question". For more results, simply follow the [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage) tag.

Comment: On a lot of devices it's set to 10% of the partition size rather than 25 MB, which is pretty absurd on devices with lots of storage.

Comment: Full ack to both: Yes, some have the 10% rule (which was not clear to me at the time I wrote the answer) – and yes, with today's devices mostly having at least 4, 8 or even 16 GB internal storage, that's an absurd rule at least for the latter two. But nothing we can do about that, unfortunately (except for installing a custom ROM maybe) …

Comment: Neither of your source links contains the info about 25MB

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev content of the linked pages changed meanwhile. My answer is from 1/2013, TechniPage has renewed its contents in 7/2015. I wouldn't have mentioned sources not backing my claim :) As for the 10% rule, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8118832), and also see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Answer (score 3):

The other 200 MB is reserved for future purposes 
e.g.

1.Saving cache onto disk to free up RAM

2.File System

3.Moving some processes data to SD/ Flash Memory

It is recommended that you have at least 300 MB free space in case you want to install apps. And I'd recommend using a cleaning tool such as ccleaner because android is not good at memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my galaxy tablet and what I did was basically go to app info on all of my apps and tap move to sd card if it let me. It seems to do it automatically  on its own now.

Comment: It seems the OP already has done that: *I have spent quite a long time moving every possible app to the SD card*

Answer (score 0):

Not all internal memory can be used for installing apps. I think android allot a part of your internal memory for installation of apps. When that allotted space is over, you start receiving that error message. You can try following:

1. Uninstall Apps
2. Move apps to external storage or money card. You can do that by going to app settings. You may be able to move some apps by app settings option.
3. If you're still getting low memory issue, then you use [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.move.app&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dmove%20to%20sd%20card%20app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_lBMtWM6GMYm4apmwq5AH). This is only app I found on play store which can move those apps to SD card which android app settings couldn't. But to use this, you need to be **rooted**.