# 'Insufficient storage' when installing Google play services

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory, google-play-services

Before you hit reply or scream duplicate - read through what I've done.

The phone is a rooted HTC One X running 4.2.2 and ViperX custom ROM with 836 MB free space on 'app' storage and 6.6 GB free space on phone storage (which has 32 GB total). If you didn't already know, the phone has no microSD slot.

1. Already seen [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space), and it does not apply. My `/cache` directory has 314M free space available.
2. Already deleted `/data/app-lib/com.google.app.vending`.
3. Went to app settings for Google Play Services, hit 'clear cache'.
4. Emptied app and Dalvik caches, rebooted.
5. Fixed the same problem for Titanium Backup by deleting the relevant directory under `/data/app-lib/` and reinstalling.

**Update**:
Directory listing -

```
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   492M   128K   492M   4096
/mnt/secure            492M     0K   492M   4096
/mnt/asec              492M     0K   492M   4096
/mnt/obb               492M     0K   492M   4096
/system                  1G   915M   344M   4096
/data                    2G     1G   966M   4096
/cache                 314M     5M   309M   4096
/rca                     5M     4M     1M   4096
/rfs                     5M     4M     1M   4096
/devlog                 21M    16M     4M   4096
/data/DxDrm/fuse: Permission denied
/mnt/asec/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro-1     2M   100K     1M   4096
/storage/sdcard0        25G    18G     6G   32768
/mnt/secure/asec        25G    18G     6G   32768
/mnt/asec/com.jarodyv.livewallpaper.matrixglpro-1     2M   604K     1M   4096
```

Comment: Just for clarification: What do you consider "app storage", and what "phone storage"? Both terms usually refer to the same place (`/data`). Could it be you mean this by "app storage", and want to refer to the *internal SDCard* with the other term? If not, could you point to the partition you're referring to? "Insufficient memory" refers to `/data` usually (for details, please see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)).

Comment: The terminology used by the phone..app storage is about 2 GB, and phone storage is what is advertised as '32 GB' - used for storing media as well as apps that can be moved to SD card. Pretty confusing the way different manufacturers refer to it, but I hope you get the picture.

Comment: Yuck, that's strange. Going by your *mountpoint* (not "directory") listing, there should be no "insufficient storage" reported, so that rather looks like a bug.