# mobile rooting problem

Tags: root-access

I am using Samsung GT-S6312. I just rooted my mobile with frama root. I haven't installed any custom firmware, nor a custom recovery. I've got some problem. If I install some apps like Whatsapp, way2sms, it's notifying me that I don't have any space, however I still have 400Mb in my internal memory.  I can install some other apps, including Facebook, Hike etc. 
I have tried to unroot my phone without success. So if I reset my mobile, does it unroot my mobile successfully?

Comment: You jump pretty quick to the conclusion that rooting was the cause for the installation problems. The problem could be completely unrelated to rooting. See for example http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to unroot your device you need to flash the stock ROM again over to your device. For getting the stock ROM for your device try heading over to the sammobile/firmware section and get the appropriate stock ROM available for your Samsung GT-S6312, once you get the stock ROM use the ODIN which can be easily searched over the Google, download and use it to flash the stock ROM over your device. Once the flashing process completes your device will get unrooted.