# Error - Insufficient storage - Nexus 7

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-7, insufficient-memory

```
Device: Nexus 7 (2013 WIFI)
ROM: AOKP_FLO_KITKAT_NIGHTLY_2014-07-31
Rooted: Yes
Recovery: TWRP (Not sure if this is needed)
```

I am posting this because I recently started getting "insufficient storage" error on my device. I've had this before and I knew exactly had to fix it because I had come back from a vacation then and there were a lot of pictures on the device; So it was a simple matter of moving all the pictures and videos off the device for it to start working again.

This time however it is a little confusing for me. I will start with some pictures:

[image: Settings > Storage] [image: ES File Explorer]
<sup>*Settings > Storage* / *ES File Explorer* > Top_left menu > Tools drop-down > SD Card Analyst (click images for larger variants)</sup>

So far everything looks fine, I seem to have a lot of space left to install one measly app right? Just to confirm, I used Clean Master to try to move some apps to device storage:

[image: Clean Master]
<sup>Clean Master > App Manager > Move</sup>

No gimmicks here, Clean Master sees that I only have one storage medium on my device. So why do I get these errors?

[image: Google play] [image: AIDE]
<sup>*Google play* (Trying to install an app that is less than 1MB in size) / AIDE (Trying to run an app)</sup>

I'm just confused about the whole thing. Everything else seems to be saying I **have** enough space, but apps are not being installed because I **don't have** enough. What can I do here?

EDIT: Even more weirdness, it won't let me install the 300Kb file with the image I posted above, but it lets me install a [3Mb file](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en) from the playstore. Basically I can install some apps but not others and it doesn't matter the size, my device just wants to make me crazy no problem. Ex. [This app (2.6M)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyingottersoftware.mega) installed fine, but [this one (2.1M)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.sethyx.aokpush) didn't due to "Not enough space".

**What I have tried:**

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1834105
- Installing and running DiskUsage and here is a screnshot:

[image: DiskUsage]

Couple observations:

--> It let me install this App and still not letting me install the other apps I have tried with the insufficient memory message still showing

--> The above pic shows that I have enough space left on the `/data` partition to install atleast A LOT of apps!

- Output of running the `df` command:

[image: Terminal Emulator]

Note I have tried the solution posted at the "Possible Duplicate" link and it did not work nor did I expect it to. The problem here is not that I have insufficient space to install apps because as you can see, I have a lot of space and I am able to install some apps. The problem is deeper than that and probably has to do with the way files are installed on my tablet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space)

Comment: Hint: A good starter on this topic is our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Contains first aid, and links to several of the most important posts here for that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have tried the solutions there, but either some solutions are not applicable to my situtation (i.e. My tablet uses solely internal storage and I have over 8gb of internal storage left and I can still install some apps but not others) or they are not for my device (Most of the solutions are for devices other than Nexus 7 or related to android market which has long been replaced by play store)

Comment: So the problem seems to have resolved itself. After restarting for the umpteenth time, it is finally working now. My God!

Comment: Have you tried factory resetting? Keep a backup beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You might have needed to wipe the user cache, which I think happens automatically over time (hence the umpteen reboots solving the problem).

Answer (score 0):

try to flash EBR to increase your system memory from phone memory.
you can find about this in detail if you search with your phone model.

Warning !
this process might cause your phone DEAD!
void warranty and boot-loops

this process is done with specific ROM flasher of that phone brand.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my phone and found that i had a lot of pictures/videos text messages voicemails taking up most of my storage once i deleted them the insufficient storage went away