# Galaxy S3 insufficient space

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3, insufficient-memory

I've got a couple GBs worthof space and my internal and external SD storage are about at 25% full each. No matter where I try to download apps to, it says I've got insufficient space.

I've already deleted everything I don't need, cleared caches, and updated the Play Store. Sometimes it will let apps update by themselves automatically and have no issues, but other times it will so say I lack space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Space Cleaner | Boost & Clean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orangepoint.spacecleaner) by Uniblue. It's super easy to use, it cleans all cache and junk from my Android device, and effectively allows me to manage my apps to create more space on my device.

Comment: Installs: 1000-5000. I'm curious, are you affiliated to this app?

Comment: A friend of mine suggested it to me, as I kept getting that silly error. Affiliated? what like work with the company? no, just a happy user

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all check your internal storage for space I know you have checked your internal storage and SD card its has GB's of Space but this time check only the internal storage I am sure you must be lacking internal storage because apps download at the internal storage.

Comment: I did & it says I have 2.71gbs of space left. I also have it set to download automatically onto the SD card. (If possible) & the error happens either way. Even if I switch it to the internal storage. I've no clue how to share pictures but, uhh.. See if my profile pic helps any? It should show my storage data.

Comment: Then I guess that only leaves me saying try clearing the cache and the data stored by the Google Play Services and Google PlayStore app. Other than this I can't suggest anything out, maybe you should wait a bit more while to know what other members have to talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Repair/reinstall the OS again using [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/). Read this [F.A.Q](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00059173/81104) before doing so.
*Note: You don't lose any personal/user data on doing this.*