# Can't download any app why?

Tags: google-play-store

Okay i can't download any app to my phone without it alway sayrERROR DOWNLOAD APP THERE IS INSUFFICIENT SPACE ON THE DEVICE. I'VE ONLY GOT 1 APP MYSELF DOWNLOAD TO MY PHONE IT CALKED VAULT FOR MY PICTURE SO HOW DO I FREE UP SPACE I'VE CLEAR A THE CACHE I HAVEN'T CLEAR THE DATA BECAUSE I DON'T KNOW IIF I'M SUPPOSED TO PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Please don't use ALL-CAPS. It's considered as shouting and nobody wants to hear that. Also, please noted the full, original error message. And please fix typo/grammar if there's any.

Comment: Additionally: This question has already been asked multiple times (hint: we've got a "search box" on the page ;) Please find the answer to your problem here: [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27083/16575)

Answer (score 0):

It means you device doesn't have sufficient memory to help you in getting more apps. What you can do is:

1. Get and SD card from your nearest store and move apps to SD card.
2. You can also try various cleaner apps available to free up your temporary memory.
3. You can also try un-installing apps that you don't use.

Note: If you are rooted user then only you can get rid of the bloatware loaded over your device.