# ADB version of these terminal emulator instructions?

Tags: adb, insufficient-memory, motorola-moto-g, terminal, cache

I have the "Insufficient storage" bug on my Moto G X1032. This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space) fixes it with the terminal emulator app, which i can't install.  They recommend performing the following commands in adb if that's the case. These commands aren't working, so i assume ADB uses different equivalents. Hopefully you can translate:

"After browsing around, I found out that the cache folder (that I assume used by the market) is using small partition (around 20mb in my case). So to solve this we need to change it to bigger partition.

You gonna need Android Terminal Simulator or equivalent terminal app. This will also require your Android rooted."

```
su                                    // Root permission request will be shown: you need to approve it. 
cd /
umount /cache
mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs  // To set the folder access to rw – read and write
rmdir /cache                          // Delete cache folder. I'm personally using root explorer to do point 5-6.
mkdir /sdcard/cache 
ln -s /sdcard/cache /cache            // To link cache folder to /sdcard/cache – which should have bigger partition size
```

(Text next to `//` indicates a comment above. Text before `//` is the command to be used.)

Comment: You can use all these commands, if you run `adb shell` before you enter them.

Comment: rmdir /cache returns `device or resource busy`.

Comment: Hmmm, I never had such an issue. Probably some process is accessing the folder constantly. Remember that `/cache` is a link to a device and not a regular folder.

Comment: I stopped every process i could, but still nothing.

Comment: I've also turned off all background processes in developer options.

Comment: Well, it's Android itself. If you can boot into recovery, you can easily select *wipe cache*  and simply wipe the cache like that, without those commands. Also: Are you sure you ran `umount /cache` successfully? Otherwise it's no wonder why the device is still in use.

Comment: Huh. Now i'm getting `failed: Invalid argument` in response to`umount /cache`.

Comment: You probably cannot do that with the device "fully booted up". Try booting into recovery mode and see if the device is detected by ADB then (not all recoveries do support it).

Comment: You can NOT remove /cache, it is a partition mounted at /cache. You can try manually flushing cache by running     `rm -fr /cache/*`

Comment: `rm -fr /cache/*` is accepted, but `ln -s /sdcard/cache /cache` returns `ln: /cache/cache: Read-only file system`. Maybe it's because my X1032 has no external SD card?