# Play store show only insufficient storage only after downloading

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

I have galaxy y dous .When I download apps from play service it shows insufficient storage only after download completes.After that even when I remove some app I have download app again to install.Is there any way I can prevent it .Or is there any way to get the apk from first download itself.

Can I get the APK on first download so that I can avoid downloading same again and again until it says memory available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/google-play-error-downloading-app-insufficient-space)

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times for many, many devices. Please [do more research to find a solution](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=insufficient+storage) before posting a question that has been asked hundreds of times before. Thanks!

Comment: And for a starter: as @paulmz has pointed out, this question pops up multiple times a day (at least it feels like), so we've setup some first-aid in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) which should help you. Looking for "prevention", a good reading should be [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575)