# Application doesn't get installed : insufficient storage available

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory

I have around 50MB of internal storage left and some 1.7 GB of external storage left in my phone. But when I try to download and install any application from google android store,I get a message *insufficient storage* and the application though downloaded doesn't get installed. Why is this ? Earlier it worked fine from the same store.

For instance yesterday when I tried to install *whats app* I got the same message. What can I do about this ?

Comment: Please check [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it/27130#27130) which discusses this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install anything on htc thunderbolt](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-anything-on-htc-thunderbolt)

Answer (score 2):

I have had this in the past and been able to fix it by rebooting the device

Comment: restarting the device ? I have done it many times

Answer (score 0):

While not directly answering your question the [Apps2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) app might be helpful here, not just to move apps from internal memory but for it's feature to clear the cache of all apps in one go. If you have installed a lot then it can be a bit of a chore to go into each and choose Clear Cache. This app allows you to do them all in one hit.

Answer (score 0):

same kind of a situation happened to my SMASUNG GALAXY S2 and i could solve it by following the below steps

1. Open the phone app and switch to keypad.
2. Dial *#9900#
3. On the screen that appears, click on the button labelled "Delete
   dumpstate/logcat"

thank you..