# Running out of Memory while installing SPB Shell 3D APK

Tags: internal-storage, installation

I am using LG P500 phone, running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

I am installing SPB Shell 3D APK file which I got from internet.

After some time it shows error that **Memory Full, Please Uninstall Some Apps to Free Memory**

Though I have 50 MB Free memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

50 MB is not much. Consider that for installation, the `apk` gets probably temporarily stored there (in `/data/local`(not always sometimes it's in the `/cache/download/` folder) -- at least that's what the playstore app does, I'm not sure about a "local install" where the `.apk` probably is available from your sdcard) for processing, then gets installed (below `/data/app`) and initializes its data (below `/data/data`). And during all that, it should leave enough free space to allow all other apps to work normally: Creating temporary files, log files (at least the latter again being stored below `/data` in many cases, e.g those you can access via `logcat`), and manipulate their data (guess where -- yes, again below `/data/data`).

So you see: Most of these actions take place on the `/data` partition. Now look what size the `.apk` of *SBP Shell 3D* has. Something about 10..15 MB? So when installed, it creates its data structure below `/data/data` as well, which adds to this. And during all that installation process, free space probably falls below 30 MB (if it really requires a copy in `/data/local` for the install, even below 20 MB) -- which is why the system alerts about "free space getting low".

The solution already came with the warning: Uninstall some apps. Or move some bigger ones / rarely used apps to SD, if possible. Or clean up some cache -- but that will only help temporarily.

You might also want to check some other space/installation related questions here:

- [Why is “insufficient storage” wrongly reported when installing an .apk via adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/why-is-insufficient-storage-wrongly-reported-when-installing-an-apk-via-adb)
- [Is there a way to workaround the phone memory limit for installed apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/is-there-a-way-to-workaround-the-phone-memory-limit-for-installed-apps)
- [Why can't I install apps when I have enough storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25200/why-cant-i-install-apps-when-i-have-enough-storage)
- [Application doesn't get installed : insufficient storage available](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27265/application-doesnt-get-installed-insufficient-storage-available)

could be good starting points.

Comment: I cleared 60MB of space in Phone Memory, then also it is not working. Do you have any idea whether SPD Developers are doing this thing from Application ?

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe you ask them, you shouldn't be the first encountering it if that is the case.