# I keep getting storage errors but I have plenty of free space, what is safe to remove from internal storage?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sd-card, internal-storage, motorola-flipside

I keep getting these errors:

[image: phone screenshot #1: install errors]
<sup>Screenshot #1: install errors (click image to enlarge)</sup>

But according to the storage settings I should have plenty of free space:

[image: phone screenshot #2: free space]
<sup>Screenshot #2: free space (click image to enlarge)</sup>

I'm assuming, from reading similar questions, that it needs more space to perform the install even though I've moved every app possible to the sd card. I have cleared the browser cache and went through and cleared the cache of every other app, bringing me up to ~15MB. I used Ti to integrate 2 updates into the ROM, and that freed up enough space to update Dropbox. I installed the DiskUsage app, and this is what it looks like:

[image: phone screenshot #3: disk usage]
<sup>Screenshot #3: disk usage (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Is there anything else that I can do <del>about the 160+MiB of Data or 80+MiB of Applications</del>? (I misunderstood how the app works, it looks like the data for Dialer Storage is 12.7MiB and Browser is 11.9MiB, *what would I lose by deleting those?*)

**Update:** Here's a screenshot from App2SD:

[image: phone screenshot #4: app2sd]
<sup>Screenshot #4: app2sd (click image to enlarge)</sup>

**Update #2:** here are screenshots showing the Browser app and its caches cleared:

[image: phone screenshot #5: browser cache: cleared][image: phone screenshot #6: settings: browser cache cleared]
<sup>Screenshot #5: browser cache: cleared, #6: settings: browser cache cleared (click images to enlarge)</sup>

**Update #3:** As a long term update, I think this is partially a permissions issue with apps that I've moved to the SD card. I can move an app at a time back to the phone, and the update will succeed and then I can move it back to SD. Is there some sort of recursive `chmod` I can run to allow it? Here's a snippet of the ddms log when updating an app:

```
01-29 10:50:18.420: I/PackageHelper(16890): Size of container 2 MB 400941 bytes
01-29 10:50:18.428: D/VoldCmdListener(1156): asec create smdl2tmp1 2 fat {} 10096
01-29 10:50:18.428: E/Vold(1156): ASEC file '/mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec' currently exists - destroy it first! (No such device or address)
01-29 10:50:18.428: W/Vold(1156): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 98
01-29 10:50:18.436: E/PackageHelper(16890): Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1
01-29 10:50:18.436: E/DefContainer(16890): Failed to create container smdl2tmp1
01-29 10:50:18.631: D/dalvikvm(1298): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15097 objects / 741152 bytes in 173ms
01-29 10:50:18.662: D/Finsky(16687): [25] 1.packageInstalled: Package install status for "null" is -18
01-29 10:50:18.694: D/Finsky(16687): [1] InstallerTask.cancelCleanup: Cancel running installation of jackpal.androidterm
```

**Update #4:** After going through a [somewhat tedious process of partitioning the SD for Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), then moving items to phone, and linking them to the new SD partition, the Google Play store was finally able to update the apps. I'm still really low on space though, I'll have to try clearing the browser data and the MMS messages again.

Comment: Do you already have App2SD installed?

Comment: @IMB I installed it and added a screenshot above, all apps that could be moved to SD, have been.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have APP2SD and it says there's no app to move then there's no more app to move. I get this problem also when my I update and install new apps. I assume you are not rooted so you have less options. The only things you can do are:

- Clear cache (install cache cleaner app)
- Clear data of non-critical apps like Browser, Games, etc. (Manage Applications > Select Application > Clear Data)
- Uninstall apps you rarely use, install them only when needed (e.g., I rarely Skype on my phone so I just uninstalled it)
- Try a hack which will extend/squeeze the capability of APP2SD: http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/moving-all-android-apps-to-sdcard-apps2sd-froyo/ (this works well if you are rooted, if not there's still a few apps it can move).

Comment: The first three bullet points have all been done, I'll look into that App2SD hack, thanks.

Comment: I went through those steps and there were no more apps that could be moved. The top 2 apps when sorting by size are still Dialer Storage and Browser (as indicated in the question above).

Comment: What is the "Browser" app? Is that the default Internet Browser? If it is, are you sure you already cleared data for it? 11+MB is too big for the default browser.

Comment: It's the default internet browser app. I cleared the cache in 2 places (see new screenshots above). I have no idea why its data would be that large since I only have about 8 bookmarks (excluding the apparently undeleteable AT&T bookmark).

Comment: You need to click "Clear Data"

Comment: What will I lose by clicking "Clear Data" I'm fine with adding the few bookmarks back if they get lost, but what about things like cookies, saved passwords, history?

Comment: @travis You would lose those.

Comment: @MatthewRead Ugh, I was afraid of that, what about the "Dialer Storage", what would I lose by clearing that data?

Comment: I believe Dialer Storage is where your SMS is at

Comment: Ah, I'll go through my SMS messages and clear those out, maybe that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Available space
>
> 11.61 MB

You're correct that that's the problem.  The Market uses internal storage when installing apps (even if it's installing to the SD card) so you need to free up some internal storage.  IMB's suggestions are good for that.  I also recommend using Titanium Backup to incorporate system app updates into your ROM, which should free up some space by getting rid of the second version of any system apps (the original version is kept by default).  You ought to have more than 2 to integrate?

Comment: I had integrated a bunch before, but there were only 2 when I checked today.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't rooted?
If you have, [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) is a great app to clean up system partition.

Comment: I tried that at one point and it wasn't able to free up any more. I'll give it a second chance though, thanks.

Comment: Of course, I currently don't have enough free space to install it, ha!

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your dalvik, either through recovery or straight from Titanium. Through Titanium, it will tell you what needs to be removed and how much space it will clear.