# Message Memory Full, Incoming message rejected

Tags: sms, internal-storage, ram

I got this message on my phone:

> *Message Memory full
>
>   Incoming message rejected*

I have deleted a lot of messages, and I have also run the memory cleaners I have on my phone.

What should I do?

Exactly which memory is used?

Are there alternate apps that will let me store the messages in a different location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to several sources (including a.o. [TechniPages](http://www.technipages.com/droid-text-message-memory-full.html) and [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-replenish/204368-text-message-memory-full-cant-send.html)) the cause of this problem is lacking space in your device's *internal memory*, which must have at least 25MB free space left.

T-Mobile's support pages have a [detailed instruction](http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-3260) on how to solve the issue. Though for some steps it was not clear to me what Android version (and what menu option) they were referring to, as a basic abstract the most important points include:

- **Remove apps you no longer need**
  This is the fastest solution, as it will certainly reclaim larger amounts of space per single step. To do so, you can e.g. use Androids default app manager: Go to *Settings → Applications → Manage Applications*, select the *Downloaded* tab (you only can remove apps you downloaded yourself), check which apps you no longer need, tap their entry, and hit the *Uninstall* (or *Remove*) button. In case this is grayed out, you might need to *Force Stop* the app first.
- **Move apps to your sd card**
  This option is available with Android 2.2 and higher, but doesn't work with all apps. In short, apps must actively support this -- and must *not* provide widgets and some other things in order to be moved to sd card. The built-in "mover" only permits you to move apps applying to these rules.
- **Cleaning up caches**
  You can do so manually going to *Settings → Applications → Manage Applications*, select *"All"* (not just *"Downloaded"*), tap each app, and select the *Clear Cache* button.
- **Clear history**
  This is for your call-logs etc. I doubt this reclaims lots of space.

Having followed these essential steps (which I placed in the order of "most effective first"), your problem should be gone.

Comment: So its not really related to to little memory for the messages?  Or deleted messages not being cleaned out?
(I have been deleting a lot of them)

Comment: But I only have 17.26MB internal memory free, so that could well be the case.

Comment: 17.26 < 25 -- good combined, my dear Watson :) Yeah, that will be it. You'll need to free at least ~8MB here. Keep in mind the last 2 items mentioned (cache + history) will only provide a temporary solution, as they will fill again soon. Most is gained by deleting some apps. If you can't gain enough from that, continue with step 2 (moving apps2sd). Cache cleaning won't hurt, so I'd do that anyway.

Comment: I removed some apps, and it seems when I pass that number its OK.  (But its highly annoying, I have everything I can on external partition, so they sh

Comment: To me it's rather weird that a 160 byte SMS cannot be saved unless there are at least 25MB free. It's not a really comparable size. But as you've experienced now for yourself, that is what solved it -- so feel free to accept my answer (clicking the green check-mark next to it). Luckily, there's no "I like it" button attached :)

Comment: @Izzy I know this is just semantics, but the phone also has to store the phone number, timestamp, __id, etc for each SMS, so it works out to being a little more than 160 bytes. Also, chances are at 25mb, the OS goes into panic mode and rationing off space so it can move temporary files and such around.

Comment: I have actually deleted quite a lot of messages, so it is quite cleat that it is something else than the size.  

I have accepted the answer, but I think it should actually be a "duplicate"

Comment: Duplicate of what? If you mean another question here at ASE, please name it so we link it (and close one of the two).

Comment: That 25 MB+ is important for other OS operations, not just SMS. I've noticed that Android performance degrades as a whole, when internal memory is too less(messages too many or otherwise).