# How to get rid of bogus "Phone storage full" message (cannot send SMSs)

Tags: sms, internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting a “Low on Space” warning and having other weird problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/why-am-i-getting-a-low-on-space-warning-and-having-other-weird-problems)

I tried to compose a new SMS (text message): I tapped "New Message" and I got this error message:
"Phone storage is full! Delete some files to free space".

So I deleted almost all the previously saved SMSs, and then also moved a few apps from internal space to SD card, and uninstalled some other apps. After this I had about 4MB of free internal space, but I still kept getting the same message.

So I cleared the browser's cache and now I have reportedly 15 MB (of 190) of free internal space (and more than 7 GB of free external SDcard space).

I still get the exact same error when I try to compose a new text message (I also restarted with no luck).

At this point the message is clearly bogus, or at the very least the system is low on some other (god knows what) kind of space, NOT internal storage as it says.

WHAT on earth do I need to delete to free up this misterious kind of space that somehow got low?

Comment: Also, now I tried to install an app that requires just 127KB and it said "insufficient storage available" when I habe more than 15MB free. So it looks like deleting things doesn't free storage space despite it is reported as free.....

Comment: Now I deleted the Gmail application's data, which freed about 6 more MBs of internal space (now I have 21) and now it DOES work. This makes absolutely no sense. 15MB of free space are not enough to send an SMS????? Also, I could send and receive SMSs until yesterday, and I certainly haven't received several MBs of emails in gmail in one day. So the less than 4MB of free space I had until yesterday used to be enough to send and receive SMSs, but suddenly today 15MB were not enough....?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue already a couple of times. To get rid of that *insufficient storage available* message, you need to have at least 25MB free available internal storage (source: [TechniPages](http://www.technipages.com/droid-text-message-memory-full.html), [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-replenish/204368-text-message-memory-full-cant-send.html)). To achieve this, you can...

- delete apps you no longer need
- move apps to sd if possible
- clear app caches

See also:

- [Why am I getting a “Low on Space” warning and having other weird problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/16575)
- [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/16575)
- [I can't receive SMS when I have low storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/16575)
- [HTC Incredible says SMS storage is full, but it isn't](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14731/16575)
- [How can I get rid of the low disk space notification?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23911/16575)
- [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/16575)
- [Message Memory Full, Incoming message rejected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/16575)