# Insufficient space when downloading Go Launcher EX?

Tags: internal-storage, installation, go-launcher-ex, insufficient-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Insufficient storage” when trying to install anything on htc thunderbolt](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-anything-on-htc-thunderbolt)

When I download the Go Launcher Ex App from the play store, it downloads okay but shows "Insufficient memory"(The internal memory) when it tries to install it. :/

It is a 6 or 7Mb app, where as my internal storage has 25Mb free and the SDCard has almost 1Gb free space. I don't get what the problem is.

My Android version is 2.3.6 if that helps.

Would really appreciate it if someone helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

The "Insufficient memory" error is triggered when internal memory drops below the 25 MB limit. Though you initially might have 25 NB free, after the download (which happens to be stored in internal memory, in `/data/local` to be more precise) you've already dropped below 20 MB -- so the error is triggered before the installer itself can start the installation, and it aborts.

So what you first have to do is to free some more internal memory, e.g. by moving apps to sd, clearing apps' caches, uninstall some apps you do not really need, etc. There are several questions with useful answers around here on our site. You can check the "Related" section to your question, or follow the [internal-memory](/questions/tagged/internal-memory) tag to find them.

Comment: In some cases, I have found the 25MB limit to actually be 10% of the total internal memory. When my internal storage is 4GB, the limit seems to be around 400MB. I haven't faced this post ICS, and it seems to be a personal experience, I'm not sure if it is true overall.

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh I searched that once for another question here. In the answer I compiled I also mentioned my sources. Trouble is just locating this answer... Oh I *love* our search engine: See [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/36776/16575) :)

Comment: Oops my bad! Thanks for the info! And kudos for all the links ;)

Comment: No prob -- always glad to help! :)