# Insufficient storage with Link2sd

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, link2sd, insufficient-memory

I finally got Link2sd to work. I have Nexus One with 168 MB of internal storage. After some linking, I ended with 41 MB of free space. Now I'm trying to install Swiftkey, which is 6 MB download. AFAIK, it's around 27 MB unpacked. Play Store says insufficient storage when installing.

What should I do? I need it! :)

Comment: Other items like your text/MMS messages do occupy vital space. Try clearing them or back up clear temporarily and bring it back after installation of Swiftkey.

Comment: Please follow the tag-link for [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) for details on this issue. In short: The "insufficient memory" error is triggered when free space on internal storage drops below ~25MB. Quick calc: 41MB - 6MB (.apk) - 27MB (unpacked) = 8. Clearly below the minimum required. Especially see: [“Insufficient storage” when trying to install anything on htc thunderbolt](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/16575)

Answer (score 0):

When playing with Link2Sd note that below each application you have:

- APK size
- Dex size
- Lib size
- Application Data size
- Cache size
- Total

When moving to SD card (APP2SD) only APK file goes to SD card, Dex and Lib remains in you phone memory. If you move those apps with Link2SD all files will be move to the external SD card increasing your phone memory a lot. Application Data size remains always in the phone memory so you may consider deleting this, just hold your finger and choose option to clear application data.
The last resort is converting some applications to a system apps which will move them to the separate partition releasing some memory.