# What space am I running out of when trying to install an app?

Tags: internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory, storage

I am trying to install a new app that is around 2MB ([owncloud client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.owncloud.android&hl=en)), but it fails with "Insufficient storage space...".

[image]

From the above screenshot I can't find a partition (other than the few apps) that couldn't fit around a 2MB app 5 times (for extracting etc.).

What causes the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer for the linked question states that a minimum of 25 MB is required, and you have more than that, but it seems that people get this error with varying amounts of free space, if internal storage is at near capacity. The relevant partition--where apps are stored--is `/data`, which is at 97% capacity.

Comment: @AdiInbar There sure are a lot of questions like this. The only ones I found with my quick look were more like "How do I free more space?" or "How to increase my space (SD)?". Should have searched more..

Comment: @AdiInbar Want to turn that second comment into an answer?

Comment: Some first-aid and pointers on this can be found in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Also the 25 MB limit might be an "estimate", or have increased since. I could also imagine it fires at 95% or something alike now. So it's nothing but a "rule of thumb" to be interpreted as "little or no space available here".