# I get an insufficient storage space error when trying to download an app and I have several gigabytes of free space

Tags: applications

I have my phone set to use my SD card as default storage. When I attempts to download the Facebook for Hulu app from the Google store it always gives me this error message. I checked both apps both take around 40 some odd megabytes. I have around 4 gigabytes of free space on my SD card. I have around two gigabytes of free space on my internal storage. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: related post http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app

Answer (score 0):

Apps don't necessarily install on an external SD card. Normally, they would install on the system memory and then, if capable, the app can be "moved" to the SD card. Moving still leaves part of the app on the phone memory and usually increases the overall size of the app.

Long story short- make sure you have room on your device's internal memory to install apps.

Comment: I have two gigs free on my internal memory. the app takes around 44 megs. Thanx for the suggestion. this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me all the time. The problem with my phone was that - Despite 4GB of internal memory and 8 GB SD card, it kept giving me that error. The operating system had made a partition in the internal memory of 4 GB where it stored the ROM and necessary apps. It will not store any other app data like Facebook, whatsapp, etc on the remaining internal memory. It kept using the small partition it made in that internal memory.

Thus I had to keep moving and clear data all the time.

I searched on XDA for a memory fix solution for my phone and it worked.