# APK Installation Error

Tags: applications, apk

I have downloaded 3 apks:

- 5.39 MB
- 1.04 MB
- 4.32 MB

Now, the problem is when I tried to install the first 2 apks, I get an error message.

> Out of space
>
> The apk couldn't be installed. Free up space and then try again.

Upon installing the Third apk, it gets installed.
Now I go to Settings > Device Group > Application manager, to see how much space are still available on my device, and it's 422 MB.  My device still got more space yet, but why I can't install an apk just a 1 MB?

> My device is running 4.4.4 KitKat

**Please help!**

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app)

Comment: On Addition, I also move all apps to SD Card that support `move to SD Card`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cached data and then reinstalling 
Clear cached data by going in Setting>>Storage>>Scroll Down a little you will see Cached data,Press on the Button to clear cache. Should Work