# ERROR : I have enough memory but showing Insufficient storage; can't install app

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-e

I am using Moto E(1st Gen.), updated to Lollipop.

Now my internal storage *235mb* free,

[image]

I try to install **hike** messenger app. Which has only *16.78 mb*,

[image]

But, when I try to install am getting an error message as **insufficient storage**,

[image]

When I click view storage,

[image]

How to solve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used Lucky Patcher by any chance? Sometimes orphaned .odex files can cause this glitch. If you have, [follow the directions here](http://www.techzilo.com/fix-titanium-backup-could-not-be-installed-free-up-some-space-and-try-again-error/) to fix the issue. Alternatively, you can manually delete any relevant .odex files from /data/app/ - they'll be stored in the folder of the app you patched. Normally you should only have to delete .odex files relevant to the app that's giving you the install error.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an SD card issue. Try removing the SD from your device if you have one, and try re-installing this application. Sometimes when you have under >500mb of storage left, your SD card may try to split the download between the internal and external storage.

Maybe try deleting some pictures, applications, or videos you don't need anymore. You can use Google Drive to back-up your data.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me most of the time. Clearing  cache for the Play Store works, but don't get your hopes up, it only works a couple of times. To clear the cache, try:

Settings → Apps → [offending app] → Clear Cache (a button).

On Marshmallow, this becomes:

Settings → Apps → [offending app] → Storage (tap on the item) → Clear Cache (a button).