# Unable to download apps

Tags: internal-storage

I have a zte phone. No space pops up when downloading apps; however,  have phone storage space of 411MB available and SD space of 1.82 GB available.  Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Android 6 or 7 and use sdcard as internal storage. Use cyanogenmod if zte won't accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to download an app from Google Play App Directly, I would suggest to try an alternative approach - install the `app` through web open a browser either in PC - [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en)

1. Search for an app

[image: pic1]

2. Choose Device
   [image: pic2]
3. Click install, and view your phone for the push notification (Turn on WIFI).

And better check in the `Settings` - Transfer some app in SD card.

The other step will be - download APK watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WP_RaUhJVWE)

Comment: He doesn't have problem with installing itself, but with storage.

Comment: It's confusing then - the title should be related to storage not `Unable to download apps`.

Comment: it's not confusing you just should read a question

Comment: Sorry , I only answer what she put in the title. I know that she has a problem with the storage. As I understand, there is no pop up window to inform her that she has more space or not either in Phone / SD. Therefore I try to suggest to push notification the download through install in web and maybe it will pop up without entering `Google Play`,  also that is why I suggest to transfer some app in the SD.

Comment: Nope, she has problem because that popup shows

Comment: hhmm.. `NO space pops up when downloading apps`.  Ok,  whatever :/