# Low space on HTC Desire with CyanoGenMod 7.1: how to solve it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, app2sd, internal-storage

I have an HTC Desire GSM.

This phone has the known problem of limited memory, so that it was impossible to install more than a couple of apps without running into the "Disk space low" problem.

So I rooted it, installed CyanogenMod7 and App2SD. I moved to the SD card almost all of the application (except those that needs notifications: those won'd work if moved to the SD).

Still, I periodically get the "Low space" message; it is as if the apps were storing their data on the phone memory. If I go to settings -> applications and clear some application's data, then clear the browser cache, I get rid of the message for a couple of days.

How can I definitely get rid of the "Low space" notification, while keeping my applications installed?

Please note:

- I've read that it could be possible to repartition the SD card and "mount" it so that it extends the phone own memory. I've seen several conflicting instructions about the procedure (and, e.g. the order of the partitions on the SD card) and, while I managed to partition the card, I never managed to have Android "mount" the extra partition. I've also read instructions saying that recent versions of Cyanogenmod don't support the sd partition anymore.
- The phone is already rooted, hence solutions requiring root are OK
- I installed Cyanogenmod 7.1.0, but I have not particular preference to that mod. If necessary, I am open to install any mod that works on the phone and is stable for everyday use.

UPDATE:

[This wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Apps2SD) is the reference that says that the sd partition is not supported anymore:

> Apps2ext (previously called apps2SD) moved all user installed apps to a secondary ext partition on your sdcard. This method had the advantage of being straight forward and simple, However, it had the drawback of being difficult to set up. This method is no longer officially supported by CyanogenMod

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help . Could you have a look over there?

Comment: @ce4 my fault, I should have mentioned I had read that question before asking my own. I don't think it is a duplicate because 1) the other question is about using the original firmware and 2) the top answer is about using titanium backup to "integrate" app updates into the rom, but I have no such updates (I checked).

Answer (score 4):

Many ways lead to rome:

1. Try a ROM that specifically fixes your problems: I use an ICS build, Sandvold's [ICS for Desire](http://www.sandvold.as/changelog.htm) which comes with 4 different App2SD methods included (XDA [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355660)) which I find rather stable. You can have a look over to XDA's Desire [forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=628), to search for more roms.
2. Use **Link2SD**, create a 2nd ext2/ext3/ext4 partition that a choice of your apps get moved to (manually) and symlinked from /data/ to. See [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) on Google Play, official [FAQ](http://www.link2sd.info/faq).
3. CM7 also supports the standard **move to sdcard** method that you can also use (and might already be aware of. Downside: /data get's full anyway really soon)
4. You could try to flash a different bootloader (called **hboot** on desire, that has another partition layout. See [Alpharev](http://alpharev.nl) for instructions and downloads, there's **data++** with 180MB and **cm7r2** with close to 300MB free for apps at the expense of shrinking other partitions (/system, /cache/, ...). Not every ROM fits all of these though. **WARNING**: Not for the faint hearted! Read about the risks!

Comment: I also like DroidSail Super App2SD Lite. On my HTC Droid Incredible, the problem lies in the data partition, not the app. You should post that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [post on the cyanogenmod forum](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/52096-low-internal-memory/) that explains how to solve the problem.

I followed it and have had no more problems! It boils down to this:

1. use the Rom Manager to partition the SD card
2. Install [S2E](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e) and use it to move the caches to the SD card

Answer (score -1):

i was exactly like you but with cm7.2 i partitioned my sd and mounted it easily using terminal emulator writing only one line of on each boot and then quick reboot from link2sd then everything is completely fine that line is:
mount -t ext2 /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data/sdext2
but before all that you should open link2sd and select the ext2 then reboot

Comment: Does this mean that you have to do the mount *each* time you reboot your phone, or turn it off/on?

Comment: no. his rom doesn't support /etc/init.d/* scripts (where link2sd would place a mount script). Cyanogenmod supports this, so you just could give that a try. You have to repartition your sdcard though. Plus: You should not run your phone without *that* exact sdcard anymore (because apps have been moved in a non-standard app2sd way)

Comment: @fdierre well I don't reboot every day so it works fine with me

Comment: @ce4 he can use the sdcard without formatting or losing apps just use link2sd and it will do it all for you