# HTC Desire Bravo low memory

Tags: htc-desire, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

It is constantly saying "Phone memory storage space is getting low" after I download app.
Even if I move that app to SD (some apps cannot be moved) it is still low memory, about 18mb of 156mb.
How to solve that problem?

Comment: I'd suggest to 1. check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for "first aid", then 2. check the [most frequented questions of that tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory?sort=frequent) (you always can hover your mouse over tags and select "info" for the tag-wiki, or "faq" for most frequented questions on that topic). After that, either update your question with what's still missing, answer your own question if solved, or simply delete it if the same issue was solved in another question already :)

Comment: On the same boat, I'd like to point you my answer here, http://android.stackexchange.com/a/14862/8197