# Internal Memory getting low despite apps are moved out using Link2SD

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, link2sd, htc-explorer

There might be similar questions. I don't want to open those old question.

This is what I have done:

- I have rooted my phone.
- I have installed Link2SD.

It was working good. Suddenly I started to get interal storage full warning.
I uninstalled apps one by one. I got some space in internal storage. I got about 80MB. I should get 150MB. Anyway, I am now installing apps one by one. Whenever I install an app, the internal storage is going low. Once I moved the app using Link2SD, I am getting some space.

But the problem is, I am not getting the same amount of space. So if I install few more apps, the internal storage will surely go down and i will get warnings.

What is the best solution to keep the apps in SD card? So I can keep good internal memory.

Comment: Have you seen this: [HTC Desire low on internal storage, I'm clueless -- Any help?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5519) Can you elaborate as to why your question is different?

Comment: Please see the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for your storage problem, plus the [link2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) for some background on Link2SD. Special quote from the latter: *Link2SD does not move application's private data files; it moves apk, dex (dalvik-cache) and lib files.* So with any new app installed, even if moved with Link2SD, additional internal memory will be used for the apps data (e.g. database files).

Comment: @Al Everett That question and answer didnt solve my problem. I guess it would not have solved the problem for the asker!

Comment: @Izzy how do we move data files too? I just found that twitter, facebook and g+ use lot of data. If i clear them, i am getting more space and i need to re-login. They fill the data very fast.

Comment: @Mahesh take a look at the [link2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) :) Or guess the word: App2SD -> Link2SD -> *Data2SD* :)